# Stock keeping System

Tags: php, sql

I want to develope a system where I have 38 stores and I want each store to login and enter their stock.
When a certain store logins they should only access their stock  only not for anyone else.
Should I have a table for each store on the sql database?

someone advice please

Comment: Start off with deciding what data you want, then design your program, your database, using normal form and best practices. If you get stuck, submit a new question. This question is like asking: "I have an idea for a fantasy genre book about some guys and some magic rings and an evil eye, please help me write it". The short answer is NO. you should normalize your data and use row-level data segregation.

Comment: Hello, I already have a form which will collect data from the stores. only that what I need to know if I need a table for each store.

Comment: read my comment, and you have your answer

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You would need at the very least two tables. One for storing stores and other for products. One table for each store makes little sense to me.

Comment: Hello victor you  mean it is advisable I create a table for each store?

Comment: No, it's not a good practice. You need only one table called "store" and one row for each store. You should learn more about database design and normalization.